# Algorithm : calculate total price using decomposition recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm designing an algorithm that calculate the total price of a product.

The product can be composed by composite ingredient (X,Y,Z) or basic ingredient (a,b,c), the basic ingredient each is associated with a price.

The composite ingredient is itself composed by other composite or ingredient. E.g.: `X (composite) = Z (composite) + a (basic ingredient)`

Now to calculate the total price of a product, I now use a recursion algorithm that decompose each composite ingredient into basic ingredient, and sum up their price.

I want to know if there is better algorithm already to solve this kind of problems ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no better algorithm.

Comment: You can enhance with memoization (for large problem spaces) so that you only calculate each composite once.

Comment: So it's the tail recursion ?

Comment: No, it is not tail recursion. Memoization means that you store the calculated price keyed by the composite. Tail recursion would only be possible if a composite could only consist of 1 (non-memoized) element, which clearly is not the case here.

Comment: Reminds me on calculate factorial(n) recursively. Either declare a Hashmap storing the price of composed ingredients or store the price of the composed ones directly in the object.